# Can PhpStorm has Warning & Error indication next to line number like NetBeans?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Check this picture,

[image]

I know that PhpStorm has it on the scrollbar. But it still hard to identify the problem line number.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm doesn't have what NetBeans has, as it appears in your screenshot. You can enable line numbers though: File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Check Show Line Numbers > OK

Unused variables and symbols will have squiggly line underneath them. On the left side you will be able to see the line number and on the right will appear code inspection markers, if PHPStorm has to suggest improvements.

Unused symbols can be highlighted, if desired. File > Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > click Save As to copy your theme > scroll down to find Unknown symbol > click on it and choose a background color from the right side (check Background color) > OK.